# USB 2-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: kali-linux, usb, persistence

I can't seem to find any USB 2 error code list.

I'm booting off Kali 2018.2 with Luks Encrypted Persistence. I can't get past to Fail Safe, GUI crashes everytime it tries to init.
It seems to disappear when I boot to simple persistence, so I'm guessing it has something to so with the Luks Encryption?

Answer (score 0):

From kernel-source include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h

```
#define ETIMEDOUT       110     /* Connection timed out */
```

Comment: Why do you think it happens when I proceed with encrypted persistence?